# Series formula too long error in VBA charts

Tags: vba, excel, charts, error-handling

I have the following data with 23 departments. 
The row one department cells are merged.

My data is similar to the data in the image [in this link.](http://peltiertech.com/images/2015-07/MrExcel-TwoChartsPartDeux.png) I just have [23 number of 'pcts' and 'acts'.

- I am trying to make two charts using VBA; one for Actual and one For % of total by the following code.
- I am getting two graphs until in the For loop of i Column the values do not exceed 35 and 36 respectively in place of 29 and 30 respectively.
- As I exceed the values 35 and 36 resp, it shows 'Series Formula Too Long' error and the graphs are not plotted.

Why this is happening?

```
Sub TwoCharts11()

  Dim rChart1 As Range
  Dim rChart2 As Range
  Dim iColumn As Long
  Dim cht1 As Chart
  Dim cht2 As Chart

  Const StrtRow As Long = 2
  Const EndRow As Long = 6

  With ActiveSheet

   Set rChart1 = .Range(.Cells(StrtRow, "B"), .Cells(EndRow, "B"))
   Set rChart2 = .Range(.Cells(StrtRow, "B"), .Cells(EndRow, "B"))

   For iColumn = 3 To 29 Step 2
       Set rChart1 = Union(rChart1, .Range(.Cells(StrtRow, iColumn), .Cells(EndRow, iColumn)))
   Next

   For iColumn = 4 To 30 Step 2
       Set rChart2 = Union(rChart2, .Range(.Cells(StrtRow, iColumn), .Cells(EndRow, iColumn)))
   Next

   Set cht1 = .Shapes.AddChart.Chart
   Set cht2 = .Shapes.AddChart.Chart

   With cht1
    .Parent.Left = .Parent.Left - .Parent.Width / 2
    .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    .SetSourceData rChart1
   End With

   With cht2
    .Parent.Left = .Parent.Left + .Parent.Width / 2
    .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    .SetSourceData rChart2
   End With

  End With

End Sub
```

I have also [posted my question on the following links.](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/865663-series-formula-too-long-error-visual-basic-applications-charts.html#post4203479)

Comment: Well why don't you do your entire aggregation and unions in another place and simply refer that destination into the series range?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. What do you mean by another place? I am new to vba; it will be really great if you could help me out with the code.

Answer (score 0):

A chart series formula (select the chart and look at the formula bar) looks like this:

```
=SERIES(,Sheet1!$B$5:$F$5,Sheet1!$G$5:$K$5,1)
```

which means

```
=SERIES({series name, optional},{x values},{y values},{plot order})
```

When you combine discontiguous ranges into X and Y values, the series formula gets large:

```
=SERIES(,(Sheet1!$B$2,Sheet1!$D$2,Sheet1!$F$2,Sheet1!$H$2,Sheet1!$J$2),(Sheet1!$C$2,Sheet1!$E$2,Sheet1!$G$2,Sheet1!$I$2,Sheet1!$K$2),1)
```

Each of the sections of the series formula has a strict character limit, something less than 256 characters, at which point it will fail, with the error message you've seen.

What @bonCodigo suggests is to move your data from a discontiguous arrangement (as in the first colored row in the screen shot; purple = X values, blue = Y values) into a contiguous arrangement (as in the second). The charts look the same, but the formulas in the second are much simpler, and will not give you the error.

[image]